# How to get LineString s from a Geometry (Geotools JTS)

Tags: java, maps, gis, geotools, jts

I have an arbitrary list of line segments, which I want to intersect with a viewport. What's a way to obtain another list of line segments as clipped from that viewport.

Assuming the viewport is a square. Any given line segment can be discarded (if the segment does not intersect the viewport) or clipped if it intersects the viewport in at least 2 points.

I have this so far:

```
public LineString [] intersectWithViewport
    (Linestring[] input, double centerX, double centerY, double length) {
    GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory();
    double halfLength = length / 2;
    Coordinate upperLeft = new Coordinate(centerX - halfLength, centerY - halfLength);
    Coordinate lowerLeft = new Coordinate(centerX - halfLength, centerY + halfLength);
    Coordinate lowerRight = new Coordinate(centerX + halfLength, centerY + halfLength);
    Coordinate upperRight = new Coordinate(centerX + halfLength, centerY - halfLength);
    Coordinate[] viewPortCoords = 
        new Coordinate[]{upperLeft, lowerLeft, lowerRight, upperRight};
    LinearRing lr = gf.createLinearRing(viewPortCoords);

    Geometry viewPort = gf.createPolygon(lr, null);
    Geometry segments = gf.createMultiLineString(input);
    Geometry intersection = segments.intersection(viewPort);
    ...
}
```

How do I obtain the `LineStrings` from the `intersection` geometry?

Comment: I think you should just be able to cast intersection to a MultiLineString and proceed from there